# How do I limit a foreach loop n runs?

Tags: c#, datatable

Assuming I have the following loop:

```
foreach (DataRow dr in table.rows)
{
    ...
}
```

How do I keep it from running more often than n times?

Comment: For a new programmer, be sure to look at the answers that do explicit counters in loops, even if you ultimately go for one of the `Take(50)` approaches.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram: Very good suggestion for someone who is learning.

Answer (score 20):

In case `rows` is actually just from [`DataTable.Rows`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.rows.aspx), the simple `Take` answers given won't work as [`DataRowCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowcollection.aspx) only implements the non-generic `IEnumerable` interface, whereas LINQ needs the generic one. You'll need something like:

```
// Uses DataTableExtensions.AsEnumerable
foreach (DataRow dr in table.AsEnumerable().Take(50))
```

or

```
// Uses Enumerable.Cast
foreach (DataRow dr in rows.Cast<DataRow>().Take(50))
```

Comment: You've made me hesitant to correct typos ;) Was the plus sign at the end of the second example intentional?

Comment: @JamesJohnson: Nope, just a typo this time :)

Answer (score 10):

You could try

```
using System.Linq;
...
...
...
foreach (DataRow dr in rows.Cast<DataRow>().Take(50)) { }
```

Note that you have to call `Cast<DataRow>()` in order to convert `DataRowCollection` to `IEnumerable<DataRow>`, which will allow you to use the `Take()` extension method.

Comment: Have you tried this code? There is no `Take` method directly available to the `DataRowCollection`.

Answer (score 3):

Option 1: Have a running counter:

```
var i = 0;
foreach (DataRow dr in rows)
{
    i++;
    if(i >= 50) break;
}
```

Option 2: Use a for-loop

```
for(int i = 0; i <= 50; i++) {
    // This might actually crash if there are fewer than 50 rows
    var row = rows[i]; 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Ideally, modify your original query to only return 50 rows. There's no point in fetching more than you want to use.

Others have provided good alternatives if this is not an option.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
foreach (DataRow dr in table.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Take(50))
{
    //your logic
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `.Cast<DataRow>().Take(50)` Linq approaches are fine, but this is really a simple problem for a `for` loop:

```
for( int i = 0; i < Math.Min(50, rows.Count); ++i ) 
{ 
    var row = rows[i];
}
```